# Match recursively all the Widgets of a Shell with SWTBot

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swtbot

I was wondering if there's any way to get all the widgets in a given `Shell`, including widgets that are grandchildren of `Shell`. What's the easiest way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

A little bit more readable and extended than the only answer:

The main idea is that you cannot get all widgets "at once", you need to use **matcher**. Moreover, even when you've got the widgets, you should create a copy of them to avoid Invalid Thread Access error.

So, the snippet for matching all (in this case, all **Text** widgets, but it can be easily adopted for any type, or Widget, as in Kane's answer):

```
import org.eclipse.swtbot.swt.finder.SWTBot;
import org.eclipse.swtbot.swt.finder.matchers.WidgetMatcherFactory;
import org.eclipse.swtbot.swt.finder.widgets.SWTBotText;

Matcher<? extends Text> matcher = WidgetMatcherFactory.widgetOfType(Text.class);
List<? extends Text> widgets = new SWTBot().widgets(matcher);

for (Text t : widgets) {
  // Create a copy to work with to avoid Invalid Thread exception
  SWTBotText text = new SWTBotText (t);
  // Do stuff...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try **org.eclipse.swtbot.swt.finder.matchers.WidgetMatcherFactory.allOf(WidgetMatcherFactory.widgetOfType(Widget.class))**